# Replace all cells with "-1" in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
               RANK      COUNT
'2020-01-01'    100         -1
'2020-01-02'     50         -1
'2020-01-03'     -1         75
```

How can I replace all occurrences of `-1` with `None` and still preserve both the `RANK` and `COUNT` as ints?

The result should look like:

```
               RANK      COUNT
'2020-01-01'    100          
'2020-01-02'     50           
'2020-01-03'                75
```

If this isn't possible, how can I dump the original data into a .csv file that looks like the desired result?

Comment: This isn't possible as integer, but you can as string/object

Comment: If for some reason you need a numeric dtype and want to avoid object, you could use Nan and convert them to float.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy or Pandas: Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value](/q/11548005/4518341). Note that `df.to_csv()` represents NaN as `''` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `replace`, replace `-1` with `""`

```
out = df.replace(-1, "")
```

```
                RANK    COUNT
'2020-01-01'    100     
'2020-01-02'    50  
'2020-01-03'              75
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the column dtypes as int. Although, OP's accepted this answer, so maybe they're OK with that? I'm not sure.

Answer (score -2):

```
df = df.replace(-1, "")
```

Second Method

```
df['RANK'] = df['RANK'].astype(str)
df['COUNT'] = df['COUNT'].astype(str)
df = df.replace('-1', "")
df['RANK'] = df['RANK'].astype(int)
df['COUNT'] = df['COUNT'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Second method doesn't work. `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: First method doesn't keep the column dtypes as int.